# How can I use orderby on ContainerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have 2 service classes both ending with Service:
TurnoverGroupWebService & CashregisterTurnoverGroupWebService.

These two classes are supposed to be automatically registered as `IReadTurnoverGroupWebService` & `IReadCashregisterTurnoverGroupWebService`, but because both are ending with `TurnoverGroupWebService`, the wrong interface is injected to `CashregisterTurnoverGroupWebService`.

Here is some code doing the registration:

```
public class AutofacHelper
{
    public static void ScanAssembly(Assembly thisAssembly, ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var registerTypeStrings = GetRegisterTypeStrings();
        foreach (var item in registerTypeStrings)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(thisAssembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(item))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .SingleInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to order the types by string length so that `CashregisterTurnoverGroupWebService` is registered as `IReadCashregisterTurnoverGroupWebService` and not as `TurnoverGroupWebService`?

I tried adding an `OrderBy` after `RegisterAssemblyTypes`, but I get a compile error because `RegisterAssemblyTypes` doesn't return a list:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(thisAssembly)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.Name.Length)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(item))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you saw, that's not really how assembly scanning works. It's a lot more complicated than getting a list of types and filtering. You can [check out the source here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/18085089ee619c1a1d915da8665b3535161fa108/src/Autofac/RegistrationExtensions.AssemblyScanning.cs). Short version: When you do this, it's not actually creating individual registrations the way a normal `builder.RegisterType<T>` is doing.

If you need to control order over registration, I'd recommend one of two things, both of which mean *not* using `RegisterAssemblyTypes`.

### Option 1: Modules

Instead of scanning for every type in a bunch of assemblies, [put the specific types you need into a module](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules.html), in the order you want, and register that module. Yes, this means you won't "dynamically scan" for every type, but it sounds like you already need to know about too much to be just doing scanning anyway.

### Option 2: Enumerate Types Yourself

Instead of telling Autofac to scan for types, *you* do that.

```cs
var assemblies = GetTheAssembliesYouWant();

// GetLoadableTypes is an extension in Autofac.Util.AssemblyExtensions
// that helps filter out types that might have missing dependencies
// or other issues that would cause problems.
var types = assemblies
  .SelectMany(asm => asm.GetLoadableTypes())
  .Where(t => t.HasThePropertyYouWant())
  .OrderBy(t => t.WhateverYourSortIs());

foreach (var type in types)
{
  // Configure this however you want.
  builder.RegisterType(type).AsImplementedInterfaces();
}
```

The point is that you need to take direct control over the registration process rather than falling back on Autofac.

---

If it was me, I'd go with modules. I've never been a fan of `RegisterAssemblyTypes` because it causes all sorts of issues where people don't realize some additional type snuck in, or some ordering problem (like this) showed up, or whatever else. Take control of the registrations and be explicit. It'll be easier to troubleshoot and figure out later, and there won't be surprises.

But I get that registering assembly types and scanning is *easy*, so that's the trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your registration order by using the OrderByDescending method after filtering the types by name endings. To resolve the compile error you mentioned, you can first filter the types and then order them by name length using the OrderByDescending method.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(thisAssembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(item))
            .OrderByDescending(t => t.Name.Length)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: I already tried moving the OrderBy stattement after the where, but I still get compile errors on OrderByDescending even after installing the latest Autofac (Autofac 7.1.0). What am I doing wrong?